# How does plato distinguish between knowledge and belief?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, plato

How does plato distinguish between knowledge and belief? How is it based in his metaphysics?

Comment: Interestingly, we have no question with the Plato tag on this topic. We do have one *two terms for knowledge in Plato*: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7789/in-greek-philosophy-what-is-the-difference-between-gnosis-and-episteme

Comment: Also, is this question for a class? (I ask because it's exceptionally clear and precisely the sort people tend to get asked in classes)

Comment: It is not for class but rather for a test that is very important for me. If that is not allowed then i'm sorry. I didn't know about it. I couldn't find a good answer so i posted it here.

Comment: Class-related questions are **not disallowed** (= they are permitted), but some of our members prefer not to be involved in these sorts of questions, and it helps to  disclose this sort of thing.

Comment: @Kartikay Sharma How about this PLATO: TRUE BELIEF AND KNOWLEDGE IN MENO AND THAEATETUS http://definitionofphilosophy.blogspot.com/2012/09/plato-true-belief-and-knowledge-in-meno.html That's how one knows to change essay topics for class, when ready made essays are posted online.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the site below, you will have a pretty decent understanding of Plato on this topic: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-theaetetus/

A quote from the site states:

> Theaetetus' third proposal about how to knowledge is (D3) that it is true belief with an account (meta logou alêthê doxan).

This is where we get the statement: Justified True Belief is Knownledge

You can also state the equation with three sentences:
S knows that p eff:

1. p is true;
2. S believes that p;
3. S is justified in believing that p.

I hope this helps

Comment: At least in early and mid Plato, it would not at all be accurate to equate knowledge with justified true belief.

Comment: @virmaior if you read Theaetetus, he clearly makes this connection

Comment: Perhaps, but my comment was merely that early middle Plato doesn't draw this connection and Theaetetus is late Plato.