Do you believe something to be the truth or do you know the truth?
I think that you know the truth when something has evidence to support it. Belief is unsubstantiated by evidence and is not knowledge. Only you know you have that belief.
For example: When a person express they believe in God they're expressing a belief that it is the truth. Another person may not share that belief because there is no evidence to substantiate it as the truth. In this example it seems this second person knows that the first person's belief is not the truth but it might also be that they believe that it is not the truth.
I have no problem understanding if something is belief or truth. But given multiple perspectives of truth, how does one decide if one believes something is the truth or knows that something is the truth?

"You know the truth when something has evidence"? Shouldn't the "something" be you to know it? Does the second person have access to first person's evidence for their belief? If not, how would they know whether it is substantiated?

@Conifold belief is not based upon evidence either person shares the same world as we do and has rhe same information the world has. An argument or evidence that turns up to support unequivocally the truth of the first person's belief turns that belief into knowledge and God's existence is no longer the subject of belief its known collectively to be true.

@Lowri This site is mainly used to promote oneself and their knowledge, and as far as I can judge, it's not to the benefit of the community it's self gratification for some, or mainly the majority.. I just ask questions most of them make sense at least to me when iam well. And that's not for the sympathy vote.

Sharing the world is very far from having the same information about it. If it worked that way we would never learn anything new and rocket scientists would know as much about rocket science as pedestrians. Many things neither are nor can be "known collectively".

This question is similar to: What is the difference between knowledge and belief?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/89830 and https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78366 and https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8053

This concept of one person believing despite no evidence and the other not believing because of no evidence, is too simplistic (and borders on being a strawman against believers). Most of the time the situation is that there is evidence, but some people find it sufficient to justify belief, and for other people it is insufficient or unacceptable.

I'm trying to stave off closure by articulating your question more clearly. I think it's an important question. Feel free to roll back edits.

Because we are fallible we can only believe to know. Everyone who is not delusional has been wrong on occasion in a matter where they were convinced to know the opposite. The Lord Almighty alone truly knows, but it's up to you to believe in Him. ;-)

I consider that it is astounding that a question like this has been closed on a group like this. The concept [is | seems to me to be] foundational. || I note that mention of God, which is useful as an example, but not necessary to this question, tends [IMHO] to make it far more likely that any question will be closed. I'm aware that that suggestion will be hotly contested by some, probably including a majority of those who tend to do it :-) :-(  .

@RussellMcMahon First, if you got points like these, please raise them on meta and not in comments. Second, regardless the object taken as an example, this topic has been dealt with hundreds of times already and no matter how you turn it, there will be a duplicate somewhere. Therefore, the fact that it is closed is justified in principle. Third, this user has the tendency to open variations of questions about the epistemology of God that do not add anything to what's already available on the site. Fourth, discussion and contest are a bad fit for SE in general.

@JD Thanks for attempting to nt close te question. Howver t is the norm for anything I ask. Please forgive me for my persecution complex.. my main point justified belief and belief are not the same. Belief is justified once that that belief has evidence to support. I think particularly with God people are convinced of that their belief is the truth, whereas those that do not, equire evidence to convince them of a questionable belief for it to be true to them..

@PhilipKlöcking I take a look at similar questions on this site and the web before I ask questions and usually find little to info. I have scored points on this website so my questions are of interest to some. I'm not obsessed with asking questions about God however I don't think there's any question more important and if I have a revelation I like to share it. I'm not prozetylising and bashing the bible at the users of this site I have given arguments for and against God in my questions.I am humble and have no prentions or ego.

FYI, Heidegger has it that the appearance is the truth of the matter. I.e. "To say that an assertion "is true" signifies that it uncovers the entity as it is in itself. Such an assertion asserts, points out, 'lets' the entity 'be seen' (ἀπόφανσις) in its uncoveredness. The Being-true (truth) of the assertion must be understood as Being-uncovering. Thus truth has by no means the structure of an agreement between knowing and the object in the sense of a likening of one entity (the subject) to another (the Object)." B&T, 261

@RussellMcMahon A sea change in this site us in progress and a number if users have begun to rally against the small habitual reflexive-tic VTCers. Just peruse the top 7 questions on meta to get a drift. So cast your reopen vote (and accept mine — merry Christmas!)

@Rushi  I have now got enough rep here to vote down :-( but not enough to vote to reopen :-( .  Here I have "power" but it's not transferable, alas :-)

@Rushi your comments are liberating.

@Rushi if anybody is going to assert something as the truth they should have evidence to support that assertion as the truth, Faith is not an assertion but that does not mean it is not the truth.

You have simply stated the well-known and widely accepted position that knowledge is justified true belief (SEP; Wikipedia).
You present the following hypothetical:

Person A expressing that they believe in God (by this, I will take you to mean they express that they believe that the proposition P = God exists is true).
Person B not sharing this belief in P, and not sharing that belief because of a lack of evidence for P.

You then ask two questions:

Does Person B know that Person A's belief in P is not the truth?
Does Person B believe that Person A's belief in P is not the truth?

Note that Person B may not know anything or even believe anything at all about what Person A believes. Nothing in your hypothetical says that Person A has shared information about their belief with Person B.
I will make a small adjustment to your questions, because it is not standard to talk about whether beliefs are true, but instead, whether propositions are true. Knowledge is in relation to propositions, not in relation to beliefs.
Therefore, with that adjustment, your questions become:

Does Person B know that P is false?
Does Person B believe that P is false?

Question 1: Does Person B know that P is false?
Only if they have justification to assert ~P: that is "God does not exist." If they have such justification, and have followed it through to come to that belief, and if it happens to be true, then they know P is false.
Question 2: Does Person B believe that P is false?
This is your hypothetical, so you'll have to tell us.

I'm proposing that knowledge does not need belief. Belief is separate to knowledge and only occurs in the absence of evidence to confirm a proposition to be true. How do you confirm a proposition to be true? And if you are confident of that evidence do you believe that evidence?

That would seem to be the point of science a theory until it's succeeded with evidence to supplant a new theory.. I believe in absolute knowledge where as science would suggest that knowledge as as is the tenets of science is not absolute and is only an approximation of the truth?

Fair enough I thought the content of the question was enough to stress my point. It was a kind of syllogism if you don't agree with the statements then for you the conclusion is invalid or the suggestion of the conclusion is invalid. I'm just asking questions and I try to make them succinct because I am not a patient reader and I don't like flannel.

You say:

In this example does this second person know that the first person's belief is not the truth or do they believe that it is not the truth?

Rational agents can disagree on judgement and justification, without a doubt, and philosophy has a spectrum of epistemological meta-theories about how to deal with this disagreement. If person A is a theist and claims there is a god, and person B is an atheist and claims there is no god, then somewhere along the way, we have two different beliefs and arguments of justifications as well as claims to truth.
One approach is to embrace absolutism which roughly claims there is an absolute notion of truth. In this scenario, an absolutist theist would claim that the atheist is simply wrong, and vice versa. In this view of truth, there is one-true version of the truth. Absolutists will often use these sorts of modifiers in their claim or use weasel words to create an impression of irrefutability. "Everyone knows this is true." (Absolutely everyone without dissent, really?) "Experts will tell you this is the true theory." (Can theories be true? Which experts?) "Almost everyone agrees that about this true version of science." (Who exactly is this almost everyone?) Often time, appeals will be made to authority. The Bible says it's true. Scientists have proven this is true. God tells us that it is true. Absolutists are big on universal claims.
In contradistinction to absolutism is relativism. With a relativist, all truths are held in accordance with some framework. In your question, for instance, you broach the topic of epistemic relativism. From WP:

Epistemic relativism is a related view. It does not question the existence of knowledge in general but rejects the idea that there are universal epistemic standards or absolute principles that apply equally to everyone. This means that what a person knows depends on the subjective criteria or social conventions used to assess epistemic status.

Lastly, one may be in the middle by recognizing that a variety of approaches to epistemological thinking might be relevant and embrace pluralism. A pluralist believes that there might be value of having religious truths and scientific truths, for instance. Life is a rather complex experience, and to try to shoehorn all epistemological thinking into one approach seems unrealistic. Pluralists are often quietists and believe that instead of trying to validate one-true-set-of-beliefs, a variety of approaches gets one closer to being a functional thinker without resolving debates in a definitive sense. This dovetails nicely with fallibilism (IEP) which says that no truth is beyond reproach.
Thus, if two people have different theories of evidence, instead of declaring one person the "winner", we can accept that there is value in the disagreement itself if each set of arguments and theories teach us something about our options on how to think. In this sense, being a pluralist also is pragmatic.

Do you believe that your right hand is your right hand?
Or do you know?
There are people starting Alvin Plantinga who know they are supported and cradled by a fundamental principle/Being. By convention in the western/Christian world that is called God.
Now you may argue: But that's preposterous! You can call it a belief; not knowledge.

Equivalently they will argue: Don't say Plantinga knows God; say he believes he knows God
To which we return to your right hand: Do you know your right hand? Or do you believe you know your right hand?

They (Plantinga and his associates) would argue these "beliefs" so called are special in that they are not inferred from anything more basic. They are Properly Basic Beliefs (PBB).
I am a neutral 3rd party:

He says it's foundational (for him)
You say it's not (for you)

If you keep the "for you", "for him" there's no dispute.
But if you insist on removing it you need to convince me why your nonbasic belief should trump his basic one.
Note the dispute is not symmetric: Plantinga claims God is a PBB for him. The materialist/atheist does not merely say God is not a PBB for them but cannot possibly a PBB for anyone at all!!
Now you may foam and splutter at the mouth (maybe you don't but most materialists/atheists who make analogous seem to!):
How can you equate an abstract idea like God with a physical sensory fact like my right hand?
An empirical caution
The fake hand experiment is a good reminder that naive realism — if I believe something is my right hand I can't possibly be mistaken — is strongly persuasive.
Yet can be grossly wrong.
A philosophical caution
Plato made the intelligible world synonymous with the real world;
The sensory, physical world synonymous with a shadow world.
You can of course choose to throw Plato out but with him goes all western philosophy:

All western philosophy is footnotes to Plato
Whitehead paraphrased

(And if you don't want to go the route of personalities replace "Plato" by "indirect realism".

I have reopened the answer on consideration of your meta-comments. I have btw certainly no anti-religious bias.

Kind of you @GeoffreyThomas! I'm sure you folks don't but the site as a whole tends to veer that--a-way

I don’t necessarily have much to say (here) about Fundamental Beings, but surely the centrality of a belief in one’s web of beliefs is somewhat incidental to its being knowledge? I might believe that I am not a brain in a vat, but surely the mere fact that it would be quite a different reality to how I believe it to be were it true is not the key thing on which the knowledge question turns?

@PaulRoss I don't understand...

@PaulRoss Reading repeatedly I think I get ur point. No a central belief is a central belief. A peripheral belief is a peripheral belief. Consider modern western cultures beliefs: Q: What is a woman? Answer: You're cancelled! Q: Did the Holocaust happen? A: You're jailed! So central beliefs are beliefs but with sufficiently more drastic consequences that they seem category-different from.the usual things called beliefs. See https://youtube.com/shorts/i1GCxtR-qRg

I do think that this post could do with a little less snark, the 'euphemism for "I'm philosophically clueless"' isn't necessary.

@Kaia snark deleted. Tnx

Perhaps you are saying that when one has been exposed to a much wider range of beliefs, one is less cavalier about asserting that one's own beliefs must be true?

@Rushi I think that’s okay to point out that there is a category difference, but I don’t think that particular difference is what knowledge amounts to. In particular, it seems like “fragility” is an important defeater to knowledge - it might be a core and central belief to me that aliens are actually in control of everything and govern all available information, but if I can give no reason for believing it or evidence to support it, it seems like it can’t count as knowing it, even if it turned out to be true! Even then, I was just a conspiracy theorist.

@PaulRoss I've no idea what you are saying! If you feel you know something, you cannot convince me about it, instead I call you a "conspiracy theorist". In the end you turn out vindicated, your conspiracy theory becomes an accepted fact. Yet you did not know all along?  Then what does knowing fact even mean?

Problem is ppl have v v different "convinceability". Leave God out, take the cleanliness neurotic — the ppl who wash their hands 500 times and yet exude a funny smell because they are too paranoid to shower properly. Tell one of them Why are you washing your hands when you just did it a minute ago? For them its obviously necessary; for you it's obviously not. Who wins?

@PaulRoss A currently active case. If I say the full consequences look quite drastic, do I classify as a "conspiracy theorist"??

@Rushi, “Yet you did not know all along?” Exactly! Knowing isn’t just that I believed it and it happened to be true - I have to have in some sense a reliable reason for believing it, or to be properly connected to the facts, or to have a good and dependable source of the information. It’s not a question of what it subjectively takes to get me to believe someone or something - if I’m just gullible, that’s not knowledge! You could have said the exact opposite and I would have believed that too!

@PaulRoss See the "fake hand experiment" above. Do you think it (the experiment) is fake? One off freak? Or do you think it happens to all of us all the time?

@Rushi, broadly speaking, I do not think people are experts about their own bodies, no!  I think we have lots of learning and study to do to gain mastery over ourselves, and most people do not.

@PaulRoss yeah people's bodies and the state of their bodies should be determined by more qualified representatives of the state.
